# How can add a tag to AWS VPC

Tags: aws-cli

I am trying to add the tags to my existing VPC.
I am trying to solve this problem using AWS cli for multiple VPC's.
But could not find the appropriate command to add the tag using AWSCLI.
Can someone please help. TIA.

Comment: You might use `--tag-specifications` option during `create-vpc` to add your tags Link to documentation [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/create-vpc.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can add tags to the existing resources using `create-tags`

> Adds or overwrites only the specified tags for the specified Amazon EC2 resource or resources. When you specify an existing tag key, the value is overwritten with the new value.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources vpc-1234567 --tags Key=Stack,Value=production
```

Or multiple tags

```
aws ec2 create-tags \
    --resources vpc-1234567 i-1234567890abcdef0 \
    --tags Key=webserver,Value=   Key=stack,Value=Production
```

Make sure your default region is correct for `VPC` or add `region` to the cli command.